# C++ to Java conversion question about extern "C"

Tags: java, c++, c

I have to convert some C/C++ code to Java. My C++ is extremely rusty.

In a `.h` file, I have the following:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* tons of declarations */

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern C */
#endif
```

What is the use of `extern "C"`? What does it mean? Is it telling the compiler that corresponding code should be interpreted as pure C, rather than C++?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers so far. The history of the code I have to convert is that it seems like a part was written in C first, then the rest was written in C++. So my header file seems to correspond to 'old' C code.

I'll convert this code into a `public final class` with static method and attributes. No overriding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's telling the compiler that function signatures should be **C** compatible. Name mangling are different in C and C++ (i.e. C++ supports method overloading while C does not) so in order to make some function calls (i.e. some DLL dynamic calls) compatible with C signature, you use `extern C` in C++ code.

[Take a look at this StackOverflow question for a great explanation on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/extern-c).

Answer (score 4):

`Extern "C"` is used to indicate a C-style linking instead of C++-style. The C++ compiler adds type information to the function symbol, but the C compiler does not.

If your library has to be used by an external application, `extern "C"` is mandatory because C++ compilers are mostly incompatible regarding type information. This is the case when you have to create a native implementation in Java, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Extern "C" is indicating a C linking style instead of a C++ style. It tells the compiler "please do not mangle my function names". It is used so that a C++ program can be linked with a C program. If you are converting something to Java, it is probably safe to ignore this. This line would only be important if you were trying to convert code to C or C++.